# Device enrolment Program to implement parental Control IOS

Tags: ios, parental-control

I recently asked a question if its possible to implement Parental control in IOS And ended up, it can be feasible using Device enrolment program in IOS. The device enrolment profile will be installed on the device and then you can control that device.

My only query is to learn Device Enrolment Program. From where i can start learning it to implement parental control in IOS app. which will restrict children to use safari and other apps if applied restriction.

One of the name of the app implemented parental control in IOS is **OurPact**